# Issue related to Dynamic grouping in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc

I have ASP.Net Application having couple of `RDLC Reports`,
I have generated report with dynamic columns using Parameter form..
now i want to Generate `RDLC Report` that use Dynamic group.. means Parameter form will have some Columns listed in `Dropdown` box, and when user select any column.. RDLC report will generated based  on group by selected Columns from dropdown box..

how can i do it using code?? please give me some basic idea or C# Syntax

Thanks..